# Buffer Through File

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, highland.js

I have a scenario where my producer runs a lot faster than my consumer with a lot of data. However, I do not want to block the producer. So the only option is to buffer the extra data through a file.

I've managed to make a non-optimal solution. However, there has to be a more pragmatic way to implement this.

I'm more familiar with RxJS where I probably wouldn't have much problem but I've just started switching over to highlands and would appreciate some advice.

```
import fs from 'fs-promise'
import _ from 'highland'

export default function buffer(id, source) {
  const ctx = {
    fd: null,
    written: 0,
    read: 0,
    eof: false,
    err: null,
    path: `/tmp/${id}`
  }

  async function drain(push) {
    ctx.fd = ctx.fd || await fs.open(ctx.path, 'w+')

    const bufferSize = 1024 * 1024

    while (ctx.read < ctx.written) {
      let buffer = new Buffer(bufferSize)

      buffer = buffer.slice(0,
        await fs.read(ctx.fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, ctx.read))

      if (buffer.length === 0) {
        break
      }

      ctx.read += buffer.length

      push(null, buffer)
    }
  }

  // TODO: What about errors?
  source.each(async (x) => {
    try {

      ctx.fd = ctx.fd || await fs.open(ctx.path, 'w+')

      if (x === _.nil) {
        ctx.eof = true
      } else {
        ctx.written += await fs.write(ctx.fd, x, 0, x.length, ctx.written)
      }
    } catch (err2) {
      ctx.err = err2
    }
  })

  return _(async (push, next) => {
    try {
      await drain()

      if (ctx.err) {
        throw ctx.err
      } else if (ctx.eof) {
        await drain()
        fs.unlink(ctx.path)
        push(null, _.nil)
      } else {
        setTimeout(next, 40)
      }
    } catch (err2) {
      fs.unlink(ctx.path)
      push(err2)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: what language/solution did you use in your example to get the async/await  constructs ?

Comment: I use babeljs for async/await.

Comment: by default highland is very lazy on the source so it is not easy to have this intermediate greedy file buffering the source while the sink works at its own pace. Note that you would have the same issue with native node streams because of back-pressure. There might be a more optimal way with highland but I don't see it right now. The main question is about reading from a file that is still beeing written. a custom duplex stream could maybe abstract this. https://github.com/finnp/node-file-duplex does something approaching but I don't think it is greedy on the source either.